# How to I extrude orthographically?

Tags: extrude, orthographic

The only options I seem to have follow the path of the normal. I want to extrude faces which are on a slant, but I want to extrude them orthographically up. I've tried picking different orientation options but every time I try it, I just get the same result.

[image: Faces ready to extrude]

[image: faces extruded but not orthographically up]

Comment: orthogonally meaning on the Z axis? In that case press Z to move up

Comment: So with multiple faces selected, would the best way be just to extrude, press Enter, then just move with G while pressing Z to move orthographically up?

Comment: don't need to press enter, you can extrude, move the extrusion, press Z (well it looks you need to press twice to cancel the normal axis) and it will move on the Z axis

Comment: Hello :). Use the little bottom left menu, set it to *Global* and use only the Z value.